# Calculating a break in the block

Tags: c#

can anyone please help me calculate the break between blocks that happened.
This is my class, and in my list I get Start and End time from the block:

```
private class Block
{
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }
  public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

this is how the time in the list looks like

```
 List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
```

[image]

```
[0] = End{12/30/1899 11:45:00 AM}
[0] = Start{12/30/1899 8:30:00 AM}
[1] = End{12/30/1899 5:00:00 PM}
[1] = Start{12/30/1899 1:15:00 PM}
```

now I want the arrival and departure times, which are the block times between Start and Stop, to calculate their sum.

```
public class Presence
{
  public DateTime arrival   { get; set; }
  public DateTime departure { get; set; }
}

List<Presence> presence = new List<Presence>();

time received in the presence list:
arrival                     departure 
1899-12-30 08:03:00.000;    1899-12-30 09:21:00.000
1899-12-30 09:36:00.000;    1899-12-30 10:34:00.000
1899-12-30 10:45:00.000;    1899-12-30 12:05:00.000
1899-12-30 13:03:00.000;    1899-12-30 14:24:00.000
1899-12-30 14:34:00.000;    1899-12-30 16:14:00.000
1899-12-30 16:27:00.000;    1899-12-30 18:02:00.000
```

this is my attempt to calculate (arrival - depature) between blocks (start & stop), but not the correct result, how could i do it correctly?

```
  double sumOfBreakOfBlocks = presence.Where(x => blocks.Any(b =>( x.arrival > b.Start && x.arrival > b.End) && x.arrival > x.departure)
                                           && blocks.Any(b => (x.departure < b.End && x.departure > b.Start) && x.departure < x.arrival)).Sum
                                           (x => (x.arrival.TimeOfDay - x.departure.TimeOfDay).TotalHours);
```

So sumofbreakofblox should be: 49 Minutes, obtained as:

```
1899-12-30 09:36:00.000 - 1899-12-30 09:21:00.000; (15)
1899-12-30 10:45:00.000 - 1899-12-30 10:34:00.000; (11)
1899-12-30 14:34:00.000 - 1899-12-30 14:24:00.000; (10) 
1899-12-30 16:27:00.000 - 1899-12-30 16:14:00.000; (13)
```

[image]

It is necessary for me to get the amount (departure - arrival) that was in the time between Start and End Block

Comment: For Block[0]: Do you want the `TimeSpan` only for 9:36 till 10:34 (which is completly in the time range of the `block`) or for all 3, where also only `departure` and `arrival` is in range?

Comment: @DominicJonas I need TimeSpan for all departures - arrivals that fall between the blocks, ie: between 08:30 -> [09: 36: 00.000 - 09:21:00] + [10:45:00 - 10:34:00] < -11: 45, so does the second block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I missunderstood the question, here is an update:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var blocks = new List<Block>
            {
                new Block
                {
                    End = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 11, 45, 0), Start = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 8, 30, 0)
                },
                new Block
                {
                    End = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 17, 0, 0), Start = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 15, 0)
                }
            };

            var presences = new List<Presence>
            {
                new Presence
                {
                    Arrival = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 8, 3, 0),
                    Departure = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 9, 21, 0)
                },
                new Presence
                {
                    Arrival = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 9, 36, 0),
                    Departure = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 34, 0)
                },
                new Presence
                {
                    Arrival = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 45, 0),
                    Departure = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 12, 5, 0)
                },
                new Presence
                {
                    Arrival = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 3, 0),
                    Departure = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 14, 24, 0)
                },
                new Presence
                {
                    Arrival = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 14, 34, 0),
                    Departure = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 16, 14, 0)
                },
                new Presence
                {
                    Arrival = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 16, 27, 0),
                    Departure = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 18, 2, 0)
                }
            };

            // group presence by blocks
            var group = new Dictionary<Block, List<Presence>>();
            foreach (var block in blocks)
            {
                group.Add(block, new List<Presence>());

                foreach (var presence in presences)
                {
                    if(presence.Departure >= block.Start && presence.Arrival <= block.End)
                        group[block].Add(presence);
                }
            }

            // calculate time per block
            foreach (var pair in group)
            {
                var block = pair.Key;
                var ps = pair.Value;

                for (int i = 0; i < ps.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i + 1 < ps.Count)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{ps[i+1].Arrival} - {ps[i].Departure} = {(ps[i+1].Arrival - ps[i].Departure).Minutes}");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Block
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }

    public class Presence
    {
        public DateTime Arrival   { get; set; }
        public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use IEnumerable<Block> to make it even more generic.

Comment: @Dominic Thanks for the help, I'm a little confused, I want the sum of TotalTime ie (arrival - departure) of those between start and stop, here I do not see where the list of Presence goes?

Comment: Then I have missunterstood your question. Maybe cou can edit your question and keep it more simple

Comment: @DominicJonas yes, we didn't agree, look at my linq sumOfBreakOfBlocks I'm trying to calculate that departure-arrival, now I wanted it to be between blocks, my code doesn't work, but in my whole question, it comes down to calculating (departure-arrival) ), which is between blockchain (start and stop)

Comment: @DominicJonas Can you still write me a timespan total? Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Save the previous Presence object, use two layers of loops, 
you can solve this problem more concisely.

```
            Presence pre = null;
            int sum = 0;
            foreach(var cur in presences)
            {
                if(pre != null)
                {
                    foreach(var b in blocks)
                    {
                        if(pre.departure >= b.Start && b.End >=cur.arrival)
                        {
                            sum += (cur.arrival - pre.departure).Minutes;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                pre = cur;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);//49
```